# How to check version of confluent platform installed

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

How can we check the version of confluent platform installed on Linux machines?

I need to know exact major and minor version to debug a issue.

Any support is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Run rpm -qa| grep confluent 
You can see the installed confluent services with major minor version

Answer (score 0):

Use the Confluent CLI like this:

```
kafka@hostname:/# confluent version
Confluent Open Source: 4.1.1
```

Comment: It only give cli information.